# NodeJS + Nginx + Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, dns, cloudflare

I use Node.js + Nginx + Cloudflare.

Node.js running at 3000 port.

Nginx have configuration:

> location / { proxy_pass http://host:3000; proxy_set_header Host $host;
>   }

This dosnt work! Why? If I dont pass through cloudflare(disable cloud) it is work but HTTPS doesn’t work and my ip is not hide!

if i use 8080 or 2052 port etc, from cloudflare list i have Error 1000!

How right use Node + Nginx + Cloudflare?

Comment: Under Cloudflare's Crypto tab, what SSL mode are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood my fault.

At nginx i used a construction:

```
location / {        
        proxy_pass http://domain:8880;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

There are many redirect was in this configuration)

New right configuration:

```
location / {        
            proxy_pass http://IP:8880;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```